# How to let flexslider's picture point to its own node uri?

Tags: javascript

I do several step below:

1 Add a PIC field to "artical" node type.
2 Make a view and set it flexslider,then limited type "artical",show "PIC" field.

And now I need to make slider that when I click on picture,the browser jump to the exect node that picture own.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the configuration in the view configuratin page, just see my screen shot.
[image]